# Spring Integration TCP Low Volume or High Volume Determination

Tags: spring-integration

Our use-case is to use a `Single TCP Connection` (never close) and perform a request-reply model, while the next message waits until the reply is received for the current request (block mode). Should we consider **60 messages / min** as **Low-Volume or High-Volume**, this will help us determine whether to use a `Gateway` or `pair of Adaptors`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would not generally be considered to be high volume, but only you can determine which architecture provides the performance you need.

e.g. the 60 messages come in 5 seconds and then no messages for 55.

Comment: Thanks Gary, 60 messages are more or less evenly distributed over a minute. Just for knowledge purpose, is that the overhead of correlating the `request-reply` in high-volume transactions the real concern with `gateways`? As anyways correlation has to be done either by the framework or the application anyhow right?

Comment: It's only an issue if the request/reply is long and you have multiple threads sending requests. The connection can only be used by one request/reply at a time; there is no correlation in this case since the reply will always be for the current request.